# python result printout twice(sqlite3)

Tags: python, sqlite

I have double-checked my database and I am confirmed that I did not input records twice into my db

I think the problem should be my function and I hope you can help me to correct it.

---

Before using function I only printout one result:
Code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT command FROM router WHERE type ="global" or function = "create vlan" ORDER BY key ASC')
for row in cur:
   print(row)
```

result:

```
('enable',)
('configure terminal',)
('vlan (number)',)
('name (vlan name)',)
```

---

After using my function:

```
x="create vlan"
y="global"
#
def readswitch(x,y):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        return read;

import database
print (database.readswitch(x,y))
```

---

result:

```
[('enable',), ('configure terminal',), ('vlan (number)',), ('name (vlan name)',)]
[('enable',), ('configure terminal',), ('vlan (number)',), ('name (vlan name)',)]
```

---

If I run code and my function together:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT command FROM router WHERE type ="global" or function = "create vlan" ORDER BY key ASC')
for row in cur:
   print(row)

x="create vlan"
y="global"
#
def readswitch(x,y):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        return read;

import database
print (database.readswitch(x,y))
```

result:

```
 ('enable',)
    ('configure terminal',)
    ('vlan (number)',)
    ('name (vlan name)',)
    ('enable',)
    ('configure terminal',)
    ('vlan (number)',)
    ('name (vlan name)',)
    [('enable',), ('configure terminal',), ('vlan (number)',), ('name (vlan name)',)]
    [('enable',), ('configure terminal',), ('vlan (number)',), ('name (vlan name)',)]
```

---

If i use my function together, it print my basic result twice too
So I think the main problem should be the function
Anyone could help me?